# Find Currently connected users in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is there a way to get currently connected users in GAE?

OR

Can we implment this feature in GAE?

I want to display currently connected users to my app in my admin consol.

Comment: what do you mean by currently connected?  do your users log in and log out?   or do you mean how many have requested a web page in the last X minutes?  what if someone is logged in but hasn't used the app in a week?

Comment: My application require to login. I want to track no of connected users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built in way. You need to keep track of them, saving a list in datastore or memcache, then list the active ones for the past X minutes.

Comment: I think this link may help with what you want.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796433/gql-query-on-date

Comment: Great I acn use memcache. My problem is that i am using gmail authentication and a single permitted user may share his login information and mutiple user can login from diff location (System).

Comment: When a user logs in, save his data and a timestamp in datastore. Then you can query for users that logged in in the past X minutes. This is the only way to achieve a "list of currently connected users". It is not 100% accurate (a user can go away during the X minutes interval) but it may be good enough.